# How to enable hl-line-mode for dired?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to enable hl-line-mode just for dired-mode, but its not working. Enabling global-hl-mode works but It's every buffer not just one which I don't want.

```
(defun hl-mode-for-dired ()
  (setq hl-line-mode 1)
)

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'hl-mode-for-dired)
```

I get this error output in my emacs log if I try to execute the the elisp. Another question is why is the error output garbled like that?

```
hl-mode-for-dired diredp-nb-marked-in-mode-name #[nil "ÁÀ!ÂÃÄ!Ä " 
[font-lock-defaults make-local-variable (... t nil nil beginning-of-line) 
fboundp font-lock-refresh-defaults] 2] #[nil "ÆÇ\"    È=ÉÇÊ#ÆË\"$   
È=*ÉËÌ#)ÍÎÏÐÑ!QAA²AA² AA²ÉÒ Ó\"Ô#ÉÒÓ\"Õ#ÉÒÓ
\"Ö#," [dired-mode-map now bdjc bdj sep map lookup-key "J" 
undefined define-key bmkp-dired-jump "
" ...] 6] #[nil "ÁÀ!Â" [bookmark-make-record-function make-local-variable 
bmkp-make-dired-record] 2] dired-extra-startup)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
(add-hook 'dired-after-readin-hook 'hl-line-mode)
```

`hl-line-mode` is a *local* hook. `global-hl-line-mode` is a *global* hook.  You want it only for Dired buffers, which means you want `hl-line-mode`.

---

Oh, and use this to turn it off:

```
(remove-hook 'dired-after-readin-hook 'hl-line-mode)
```

Comment: How did you find or know to use dired-after-readin-hook, as opposed to dired-mode-hook?

Comment: `C-h f` for each.  But you can try each of them. Either will work in this case. But you will see slight differences wrt turning on/off when you use `g` versus, say, `C-x v`, to refresh a Dired buffer.

Comment: if i try to set hl-line-mode dire-mode-hook I get the error I posted in my question. I guess a question I'd have is how does one go about finding mooks hooks? like how'd you find dired-after-readin-hook? C-h f lets you describe a function, but this assumes you already know the name to type

Comment: I use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), so I just do `C-h f hook S-SPC`, followed by other things I want to match also, e.g., `dired`. (The order does not matter, so `C-h f dired S-SPC hook` shows  the same set of matches.) But if you don't use Icicles you can get much the same information using the apropos commands, such as `M-x apropos-variable`.

Comment: Hi, dired doesn't show current line highlighted even if hl-line-mode is enabled. why?

Comment: @Amos: Given that the answer was accepted, you might suspect that something you are doing is interfering with what is expected. Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)?
 If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.